# How to programmatically trigger google home broadcast

Tags: google-assistant-sdk, google-home

What I'd like to do is write some code like:

```
var googleHome = new GoogleHomeSdk();
var devices = ['kitchen', 'lounge', 'bedroom'];

googleHome.broadcast({
   devices : devices,
   message : 'The front door has been open for 30 seconds'
});
```

Which would then do something similar to the native broadcast feature, i.e. where you type 'broadcast ' into the google assistant app on phones/tablets.

I can't seem to find any google documentation for an API like this but it seems like such a basic/obvious requirement that surely something like this must exist?

Note: I've seen a workaround where people have casted an audio file (obtained via text-to-speech service) but this isn't really what I'm after.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The platform does not provide a mechanism to programmaticlly broadcast messages to different devices.

Comment: Thanks Nick. Do you know if there are any plans for this, or is there a reason why this won't be implemented?

Comment: I can't speak to potential future improvements. For now, casting audio is the only potential workaround.